# Find word after the separator and ignore if the word is surrounded by curly brackets

Tags: php, regex, find

I have a list of language variables that are separated by (=)equals sign. Example list:

```
global.second = second 
global.minute = minute
global.respect = respect
global.Respect = Respect
respect.count = You have # ${global.respect}
give.respect = Get more ${global.respect} by giving others respect.
give.Respect = Get more ${global.Respect} by giving others Respect.
```

I've been struggling with a regex as I need to capture the whole line if a specific word after the (=)equals sign exists, ignore if the word is in curly brackets but still capture the whole line if this word exists after the one that is in curly brackets.

Using the example list and searching for **respect**:

```
IGNORE: global.second = second 
IGNORE: global.minute = minute
CAPTURE LINE: global.respect = respect
CAPTURE LINE: global.Respect = Respect
IGNORE: respect.count = You have # ${global.respect}
CAPTURE LINE: give.respect = Get more ${global.respect} by giving others respect.
CAPTURE LINE: give.Respect = Get more ${global.Respect} by giving others Respect.
```

Using google and stackoverflow I came up to the following regex:

```
/((?!\{[^\}]*?)(respect)(?![^\{]*?}))$/mi
```

but it doesn't work as it only captures **respect** and **Respect**.

To capture the whole line I modified it to

```
^(.*=.*?)((?!\{[^\}]*?)(respect)(?![^\{]*?}))$
```

but still it only captures:

```
global.respect = respect
global.Respect = Respect
```

I'm regex newbie and I can't figure out how to make this complicated regex. If anyone can help it will really be appreciated! I've added my php filter functionality in "Show some code". $search_word comes from input text box in one of my pages.

```
function FilterWord($search_word, $main_file_path, $filter_file_path)
{
    $content = file_get_contents($main_file_path);
    $pattern = preg_quote($search_word, '/');
    //$pattern = "/^.*=.*$pattern.*\$/mi";
    $pattern = "/(.*=.*?)((?!\{[^\}]*?)($pattern)(?![^\{]*?}))$/mi";
    //[^$search_word {}]+(?![^{]*})
    //$pattern = "/^.*=.*$pattern.*\$/mi";
    //"/^.*=.*(!\$*.$pattern.*)($pattern.*)\$/m";
    //$pattern = "/^.*=.*(?!\{.*$pattern.*\}*?)($pattern.*)\$/m";
    //((?!\{[^\}]*?)(kudo)(?![^\{]*?}))
    //$pattern = "/(.*=.*?)(?:(?!\{[^\}]*?)\b)($search_word)(?:\b(?![^\{]*?\}))\$/mi";
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches)){
        file_put_contents($filter_file_path, implode("\n", $matches[0]));
    }
    else{
        echo "No matches found";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeatedly match non-bracket characters, or an opening bracket eventually followed by a closing bracket. Try:

```
^[^=]+=(?:[^{}\n]|{[^}]+})*?respect.*$
```

- `^[^=]+` - From the start of the line, match anything but a `=`
- `(?:[^{}\n]|{[^}]+})*?` - Lazily repeat either:

  - `[^{}\n]` - Anything but a `{`, `}`, or newline, or
  - `{[^}]+}` - A `{`, followed by non-bracket characters, followed by `}`
- `respect` - Match the word you're searching for
- `.*$` - Match the rest of the line

https://regex101.com/r/E8lQx5/1

Note that since `{` and `}` are generally not special characters in a regular expression, they don't need to be escaped (unless the `{}`s could be interpreted as a quantifier, which is not the case here).

If you wanted, you could make it slightly more efficient with an atomic group, to avoid backtracking when the pattern is already sure to fail at that position - use `(?>` instead of `(?:`.

Comment: Worked perfectly <3 I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me "You can accept an answer in 2 minutes" Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly, yet this expression might be an option:

```
\.([A-Za-z]+)\s*(?==)(?=.*\b\1\b.*).*
```

Here, we are using a back-reference to capture our desired work, then if that word exist would get the entire line.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cIbcSH/1/)